# Select range of <li> elements in array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to create the following:

- I append multiple elements that have starting and ending date, i can
  select 1st and 5th element, but when I do that I need to select all
  elements in between as well.
- If one of those elements have `status = 'sold'`, deselect all.
- I should store start date of first element and end date of last
  element in that range.

Array:

```
[
 {
    currency:"CHF"
    end_date:"2018-12-09"
    nights:"7"
    price:"40200"
    price_bnb:"40200"
    price_sc:"0"
    start_date:"2018-12-02"
    status:"available"
 },
{
    currency:"CHF"
    end_date:"2018-12-16"
    nights:"7"
    price:"40200"
    price_bnb:"40200"
    price_sc:"0"
    start_date:"2018-12-09"
    status:"available"
 },
{
    currency:"CHF"
    end_date:"2018-12-23"
    nights:"7"
    price:"40200"
    price_bnb:"40200"
    price_sc:"0"
    start_date:"2018-12-16"
    status:"available"
 },
]
```

This is how I append elements:

```
function appendPrices() {
      for(var i=0; i < filteredArray.length; i++) {
        var ulList = document.getElementById('season-prices');

        ulList.innerHTML += `
          <div class="flex" id="prices-item-list-` + i + `"> 
           <input id="` + i + `" data-date-from="` + filteredArray[i].start_date + `" data-date-to="` + filteredArray[i].end_date + `" type="checkbox"></input>
           <span>` + filteredArray[i].start_date + `</span> 
           <span>` + filteredArray[i].end_date + `</span> 
           <span>` + filteredArray[i].currency + `</span> 
           <span>` + filteredArray[i].price + `</span>  
          </div>
        `

        if(filteredArray[i].status === 'sold') {
          document.getElementById(i).disabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

So, when I tick 2 checkboxes, i need to tick everything between them as well, unless the status of one of them is 'sold". Anyone has some advice?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: @Raptord don't know what else I can write, I added the example for array, how I append elements and explained what I would need to do, if I had more code on how to do it, I guess I wouldn't need help :)

Comment: Since you are using the back tick, you can use `${expression}` rather than using the '+' to concatenate the strings. `<span>${filteredArray[i].start_date}</span> `

Comment: Are you 'checking' boxes between the last selected and current selected, or just between any selected? If I select "jan 1" and the "jan 31"  then I choose "mar 1" will that select from "Jan 1 - Mar 1" or "Jan 31 to Mar 1 plus Jan 1"?

Comment: @DanielGale it should just increase to march 1, so if you sel 1st Jan - 30th Jan, then change to 1st March, it should be 1st Jan - 1st Mar

Comment: I would probably create a function that uses js reduce to select nodes within the selected range when there are more than one checkboxes selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful link on checkboxes:

http://rmariuzzo.github.io/checkboxes.js/

I think something like this will put you on the right track **(check a box then hold shift and click another box)**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $chkboxes = $('.checkbxs');
    var lastChecked = null;

    $chkboxes.click(function(e) {
        if(!lastChecked) {
            lastChecked = this;
            return;
        }
        if(e.shiftKey) {
            var start = $chkboxes.index(this);
            var end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked);
            $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start,end), Math.max(start,end)+ 1).prop('checked', lastChecked.checked);
        }
        lastChecked = this;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbxs"> Row 1<br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbxs"> Row 2<br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbxs"> Row 3<br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbxs"> Row 4<br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbxs"> Row 5<br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbxs"> Row 6<br>
</div>
```